# Using MeshLab is it possible to script the align functionality?

Tags: 3d, point-clouds, meshlab

I have several point clouds which I want to register in a global space. For this I have been using the "align" functionality (Without manual interactions) and I would like to script this, so this can be used on cli. I only see the option to script "Filters", so I was wondering if anyone knows if I can script the Align?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet.
The restructuring of aligning functionality from interactive tools into scriptable filters accessible from pymeshlab is forecasted for next months.